# Write string type json property to varbinary type Azure SQL column in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where I have a string type json value which I need to write to varbinary type column in Azure SQL db. No matter what I do, I get complained during copy activity that type doesn't match. The string value in JSON is already a hexadecimal, I'm just not sure how can I translate that to a varbinary type in copy activity.

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried changing the sink column type  to Byte[] array, varbinary

Comment: Please share the sample data for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

.
**To write a string type to SQL table you need to use lookup with the script activity to insert ta data.**

- Using lookup get the data from file or other location that need to be inserted.
  [image]
- After that using script activity insert the data into SQL table by converting string to varbinary.

```sql
Insert into <table_name> values (1,Convert(varbinary(max),'@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow}'))
```

[image]